# C# - Convert.ToDateTime() where Year is not specified in the Date

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-conversion

I would like to convert a list of dates that are represented as follows:

- June 6
- September 18
- November 2
- February 29

The dates themselves *do not specify the year* so when I attempt to parse them using `Convert.ToDateTime()` the current year (`2021`) is assumed. How can I specify these dates to be of a *different year*? Lets say I want to specify each of these dates are from the year `2020`. How can I specify that in the conversion? Is this where I would use `CultureInfo`?

Comment: new DateTime(Year, Month, Day);

Comment: Be very careful parsing things this way; on my system `DateTime.Parse("June 6")` proceeds without error to give the utterly erroneous result of 2006-06-01. `DateTime.Parse("June 6", new CultureInfo("en-US"))` does the right thing, but even then I'm not sure I wouldn't be more comfortable doing the parsing myself, with a fixed list of month names.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(date + " 2020", "MMMM d yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *parse* (`ParseExact`) the `text` provided; the only possible issue is *leap year* and *February 29*:

```
private static DateTime MyConvert(string text, int year = 0) {
  return DateTime.ParseExact(
    $"{(year <= 0 ? DateTime.Today.Year : year)} {text}", 
    "yyyy MMMM d", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "June 6",
    "September 18",
    "November 2",
    "February 29"
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-15} => {MyConvert(test, 2000):dd.MM.yyyy}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
June 6          => 06.06.2000
September 18    => 18.09.2000
November 2      => 02.11.2000
February 29     => 29.02.2000
```

Answer (score 1):

One line can do it:

```cs
string textDate = "September 18";
int desiredYear = 2008;

DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(desiredYear.ToString() + textDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the year post hoc.

```
var input = "June 6";
var converted = DateTime.ParseExact("mmmm d");
var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, converted.Month, converted.Day);
```